# void pyrun’ has incomplete type

Tags: c++, boost, pybind11

the current algorithm is working in boost, but it isn't working in pybind11

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        // retrieve the filename from command line argument if there is one
        auto filename = QString();
        if (argc > 1)
        {
            filename = argv[1];
        }

        initPalette();
        QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
        srand48(time(NULL))
        Py_Initialize();
        PySys_SetArgvEx(0, NULL, 0);

        // Disable the SIGINT handler in Python so we can Ctrl-C to exit
        {
            namespace py = pybind11;
            auto main = py::module::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");
            
            auto pyrun = py::exec("import signal; signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)",main);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't post console output as image. Use copy/paste of text instead.

Comment: `exec` doesn't return anything, that's why its return type is `void` (https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/eval.h#L88) so what are you trying to do with `auto pyrun = py::exec`?

Comment: I'm new to C++ I'm trying to convert boost to pybind11,  I'm trying to convert the same as the example below.
#include <pybind11/eval.h>

...

// Evaluate in scope of main module
py::object scope = py::module_::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");

// Evaluate an isolated expression
int result = py::eval("my_variable + 10", scope).cast<int>();

// Evaluate a sequence of statements
py::exec(
    "print('Hello')\n"
    "print('world!');",
    scope);
py::eval_file("script.py", scope);
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/utilities.html#eval

Comment: A general comment: Please try to always post minimal reproducible code. Here there ais a Qt dependency (not great) that whose includes are not listed (impossible to run even if I would have the dependency)